# @import styles not working in a media query

Tags: css, wordpress, import, media-queries

I am trying to import a style based off a media query but the import is not being triggered If i put styles directly in the media query they are rendered to the page.

Here is a link to the live site http://update.techbasics.ca

Here is my style.css with the media queries and the imports

I am using wordpress if that helps debug.

```
@import url('base.css');
/******************************************************************
Site Name: Tech Basics
Author: Anders Kitson

Stylesheet: Main Stylesheet

Here's where the magic happens. Here, you'll see we are calling in
the separate media queries. The base mobile goes outside any query
and is called at the beginning, after that we call the rest
of the styles inside media queries.
******************************************************************/
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/*****************************************************************
BASE CSS
*****************************************************************/

/*****************************************************************
MEDIA QUERIES
*****************************************************************/
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    @import url('min480.css');
  }
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
     @import url('min600.css');
  }
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: purple; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background: orange; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1382px) {
  body {
    background: url("../img/noisy_grid.png"); } }
/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
  @import url('base.css'); 
}
```

and here is min600.css (located in the same directory as the style.css file)

```
header {
  text-align: left; }
  body{
    background: green;
  }
```

Answer (score 26):

try that kind of code

```
@import url("/inc/Styles/full.css") (min-width: 940px);
```

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work for me? `@import url('https://rawgit.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/master/dist/hamburgers.css') (screen and max-width: 574px);`

Answer (score 13):

**Here is the solution:**

```
/* Everything 700px and lower */
@import url("./700.css") only screen and (max-width: 700px);
```

Answer (score 10):

Did you use like this?

You can write:

```
@import url('path.css') (screen and min/max-width: 600px);
```

You can add path as you use `@import`

or like:

```
@import url(style.css) (screen and min-width:600px);
```

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted but I prefer this shorthand method, less characters.

Answer (score 4):

MDN states that `@import` cannot be nested and must come **before** all other declarations except `@charset`.

The syntax is as follows:

```
@import url;
@import url list-of-media-queries;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, try to resize your window and you will see the colors changing
As I can see in my main window on my screen (1920x1080) the CSS rule

```
body {
background: url("../img/noisy_grid.png");
}
```

Located in style.css , line 37-38 fires first, that's why you can't see the orange color.
Try re arrange your css rules

Comment: its not the declarations in the media query thats not working I know they are working its the rules in the imported min600.css file thats not wirking the techbasics title should shift to the left when it is at minwidth 600px but it doesnt.

Comment: Notice how the imported style in the minwidth 600px media query also does not change to color green. This is my problem.

Comment: Try upgrading your browser or using another browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after searching without finding a good solution, I ended up moving the media queries to the imported css instead. And in fact all the style sheets are downloaded even if they are not applied anyway (see [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)).

Then what's the point of having separate files? For me, it keeps things organized. Using your example:

```
@import url(min480.css); /* min-width: 480px */
@import url(min600.css); /* min-width: 600px */
```

Then on the min600.css:

```
/* min600.css */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   header {
      text-align: left; 
   }
   body {
      background: green;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

true statement

```
@import ('filename.css') mediaType and (feature: value);
```

example:

```
@import (responsive.css) screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px);
```

notice:
if use @import for CSS file, this file should not attachment in `<link>` tag. otherwise dose not work Styles.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I should first add this meta tag in my html

```
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```