# IE11 @font-face fails when used in @media query

Tags: css, internet-explorer, webfonts

I am using the following fonts in IE11 (which are downloaded from MyFonts).  When specified in the following manner they load perfectly:

```
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/myFId"); 
@font-face {font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt'; src: url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.eot');src: url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.woff') format('woff'), url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');}   
@font-face {font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Hv'; src: url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.eot');src: url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.woff') format('woff'), url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

However, when specified inside a media-query, the fonts do not load into IE11 (regardless of screen resolution). It just uses Times New Roman instead.

```
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/myFId");
@media all and (min-width:800px) {
    @font-face {font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt'; src: url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.eot');src: url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.woff') format('woff'), url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
    @font-face {font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Hv'; src: url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.eot');src: url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.woff') format('woff'), url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
}
```

Firefox and Chrome work perfectly.  There  are no other font-face rules specified anywhere, so its not an inheritance problem.

Is this a bug or am I doing something stupid?

The idea is to assume that portable devices have a slower connection (e.g. connecting when mobile) so we skip the custom font and go for a generic one in these cases.

Comment: Possibly duplicated by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943719/import-styles-not-working-in-a-media-query

Comment: Thanks but its not a duplicate.  Problem persists when import is moved outside of media query. Question updated to reflect this.

Comment: @norin89 is on the right track. try putting your `@font-face` in another file and importing that file like the other question shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some additional research I've found the cause and solution.
The cause is that:

> The @import rules in a style sheet must precede all rule sets. An
>   @import rule that follows one or more rule sets will be ignored.
>   [Reference: SitePoint article](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/at-import)

Thankfully the solution is nice and simple.  By removing the media query from the style sheet, and placing it within the HTML reference, I achieve both requirements and also remove an extra `@import` rule:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fonts.css" media="(min-width:800px)" />
```

Comment: Just some additional information: according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), devices smaller than 800px will still download the stylesheet itself. However, the CSS declared in the stylesheet will ***not*** be applied.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach... instead of specify the font inside a media query, I would just call the font inside the media query... I believe this issue is valid, since fonts should be global and than you just call the fonts when ever is needed...

```
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/myFId"); 
@font-face {font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt'; src: url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.eot');src: url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.woff') format('woff'), url('webfonts/myFId_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');}   
@font-face {font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Hv'; src: url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.eot');src: url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.woff') format('woff'), url('webfonts/myFId_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');}

@media all and (min-width:800px) {
    div {
        font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt';
    }
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that the device shouldn't download the font if it is not needed.  Does this approach cause the font to be always downloaded?  I would expect so.

Comment: In this case, I would create an external file for the fonts and @inport this file inside the media query... I never tried this before, but it could be an option...

Comment: That approach causes the fonts to fail to load in all browsers.  Thank you for your input though, as following up on the second suggestion uncovered the answer in another web site.  I've posted the suitable approach/solution below in the hope it will help others.