# Does @import really work?

Tags: css, import

So I have placed `@import url("media_queries.css");` at the top of my `default.css`. Both files are in the same directory. I've tried to use  url  without `" "`, then tried to make it `@import "media_queries.css"` without any success. Any help?

`default.css:`

```
@import url('media_queries.css');
   ...
```

Then `media_queries.css:`

```
@media (max-width: 600px)
 {
   ...
 }
```

Before I moved the contents of `media_queries.css` from `default.css`  the `@media` rules worked.

Comment: It does work for sure, how are you verifying if it works or not? Try a css rule in your file that's not in a media query and see if it's there

Comment: Depends on what's inside the `media_queries.css`. The rule you have given definitely works. Try giving `* {border: 5px solid #f00 !important;}` and see if it works. `:)`

Comment: `media_queries.css` contains media queries such as `@media(max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 600px){...}`. It used to work before I took it to `media_queries.css` from `default.css`  Does if work in such a case?

Comment: @Huangism I'm trying to load a page from a mobile device which has a small screen. The `@media` rules defined for small screens don't act.

Comment: @TroubleZero it should work but something probably went wrong during the move. Can you update the question with a simplified version of your import code? Import should be at the top of the page

Comment: @Huangism I have. I tried taking back the contents  `media_queries.css` to `default.css` and worked perfectly. And `@import` is on top of the page.

Comment: @TroubleZero did you check inspector to see if the styles were being over written or simply not there? Perhaps give this a try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943719/import-styles-not-working-in-a-media-query

Comment: The styles are not there!