# Is there way to load css files regarding resolution?

Tags: html, performance, styles

I have a really big styles.css file, it weight 1,1MB, and I need reduce it because it's affecting  my site's performance. I was planning to distribute the code in many files, regarding the resolution and I wanna know if is there a way to load just few files , checking first the resolution or device?, 
like use @import inside media querys? 
or checking with JS ? 
or html meta tags ?
or a way to load first the header style and then call the rest ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943719/import-styles-not-working-in-a-media-query

Comment: Yes but I mean, before load the css. this is to avoid load whole css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can done through jquery on document load event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.innerWidth >= 1280) //if ($(window).width() >= 1280)
            $("head").append("<link id='yournewcss1' href='desktop.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />");
    else if (window.innerWidth >= 768 && window.innerWidth < 1280) {
            $("head").append("<link id='yournewcss2' href='midreso.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />");
    }
    else if (window.innerWidth >= 320 && window.innerWidth < 768) {
            $("head").append("<link id='yournewcss3' href='mobile.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />");
    }
});
```