# My @import query is not working properly

Tags: html, css, import, media-queries

I created two different CSS sheets (mobile & desktop version) for my website and I want the user to pull each sheet depending on the device they use. I tried to use `@import` query but it doesn't seem to work properly. I've found out through testing that the mobile version is being activated when I write

```
@import url('mobileVersion.css') only screen and (max-width: 980px);
```

though the mobile css sheet cannot be activated if I lower the width number.
On the other hand, if I put both sheets in

```
@import url('mobileVersion.css') only screen and (max-width: 980px);
@import url('desktopVersion.css');
```

the mobileVersion.css sheet cannot be activated at all when I simulate it in the inspect mode in Chrome browser.

Why is that? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but it looks like style sheets are always downladed even if they are not used [1].

Another solution would be to move the media query so the classes are only applied if they match the criteria (e.g. wrap all classes inside the media query).

EDIT: This may also help [2]

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
[2] [@import styles not working in a media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943719/import-styles-not-working-in-a-media-query)