# How to mark third-party styles as @media screen {}

Tags: css, styles, less, css-import

Is there any way to inject (not import) css files into another css file?

I am using less and trying this:

```
@media screen {
    @import (less) url("../Content/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css") screen;
    @import "fanoe.css" screen;
    @import "../Content/components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" screen;
    @import "../Content/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" screen;
    @import "style.base.less" screen;
}
```

However the above does not work - the third party styles does not render and my styles are broken because of missing classes.

(The files locations are correct)

The idea is to have all styles markes as `media=screen` so I want to have all classes within `@media screen {}`.

So I want to have something like this in the style.css file:

```
@media screen {
    .bootstrap-class { }
    .font-awesome-class { }
    .custom-class { }
}
```

etc.

Or any othe idea how to mark third-party styles as `@media screen {}` is welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943719/import-styles-not-working-in-a-media-query

Comment: "inject (not import)" - Does this mean you can't add these third-party styles in the HTML?

Comment: @tagurit I can but they haven't got media specified and google page insights consider them as render-blocking https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/blocking-resources

Comment: You can add the media query there like `<link href="../Content/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">`

Comment: @tagurit yes I know I thought I have to have also style media declared in the css file

Comment: No, that query does its job - the entire Bootstrap stylesheet will only be loaded if the user has a screen. You can see this if you change the query to something you don't have, like `(min-width: 100000px)`. The reason it's considered render-blocking is because Bootstrap has many of its own media queries within that file that aren't declared in the HTML. If you want to do the work you can modify the file to only take what you need and split it into multiple files, but unfortunately the increased latency from downloading a bunch of extra stuff is one of the downsides of using frameworks.